# Binpacking / Knapsack Optimisation problem design

Tags: multidimensional-array, knapsack-problem, bin-packing, or-tools

I have a scenario I need some help formulating the question in, so that I can properly implement an optimisation method. I hope someone can guide me a little, it seems so simple on the surface, but I am having trouble figuring out how to encode the variables, constraints etc properly.

The scenario is this:

- Multiple items need to be placed into bins / knapsacks
- Each item has two factors that must be taken into account when packing
- I have several types of bin / knapsack that can be used for packing
- The supply of bins / knapsacks is infinite
- Each bin / knapsack has constraints on each of the values from the items so that the values of the items add up in a cumulative way but cannot exceed either constraint on the bin / knapsack
- Each bin / knapsack has a different cost (price) to use it
- There is an upper limit to the number of items that can fit into a bin / knapsack regardless of which items are in it

Example:

A vector of items with two values each:

Items = [[7,6],[14,2],[27,23],[5,15]]

A vector of bins / knapsacks with first value being upper limit it can accept for item first values. Second value is the same but applies to the second value of each item in the bin / knapsack. Third value is the maximum number of items the bin / knapsack can hold. Last value is the price / cost of the bin / knapsack.

BinOptions = [[64000,1450,350,22000],[8000,450,64,8000]]

The goal is to pack all the items in the most efficient manner so as to provide the least cost (using the price of the bins / knapsacks).

I was looking at two ways the problem might be solved:

- OR-Tools with the MILP approach
- OR-Tools with the Knapsack solver

I am not necessarily stuck on OR-Tools, it is just what I have been playing with and seems to work nicely across different languages from the reports I have seen. It would be nice to be able to model this and then choose a language later.

The one thing that is probably not apparent is that the number of available bin varieties changes. Sometimes I will have two or three to choose from, other times many many more, possibly up to a hundred. The number of incoming items to pack will also change depending on the day.

If anybody can provide some guidance on solving this I would be most appreciative.

Cheers

The Frog

Answer (score 0):

the knapsack solver with not solve your problem, as it is a pure 1-knapsack solver.

You can use the MILP solver, or the CP-SAT.

Comment: Hi Laurent,

Many thanks for your guidance. I greatly appreciate it.

Just looking at the solvers it would seem that CP-SAT would be a good way to go. I have had a look through some examples and there is a part I cannot seem to get my head around. In using CP-SAT as a solver for MILP in this context I am not sure how I would encode / express the bins / knapsacks with both multiple constraints and an 'unlimited' number of each type. Is there an example you know of that you can point me to?

Cheers and many thanks

The Frog

Comment: Unlimited can be really big. Can you compute a reasonable upper bound? Then create one bool var for each pair (item, bin) ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [bin packing](https://developers.google.com/optimization/bin/bin_packing) example as a template for this problem. It uses the SCIP solver.

```
 solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')
```

In that example the objective is to minimise the number of bins used to pack all items. I think this applies in your case, especially with an unknown number of bins. Obviously, for n items the maximum number of bins needed is n, as the greatest number of bins would result in one item being placed in its own bin.

```
#> Constraints:
## Each item must be packed once
for i in data['items']:
    solver.Add(sum(x[i, j] for j in data['bins']) == 1)

## The sum of each weight type cannot exceed the capacity for that bin
## You have two weight types, k.
for k in range(2):
    for j in data['bins']:
        solver.Add(
            sum(x[(i, j)] * data['weights'][k][i] for i in data['items']) <= y[j] *
            data['bin_capacity'][k])

## The number of items cannot exceed the numerical capacity of each bin
## Let's assume this capacity is element 2 of data['bin_capacities']
for j in data['bins']:
    solver.Add(
        sum(x[(i, j)] for i in data['items']) <= y[j] * data['bin_capacity'][2])

#> Objective:
## The original objective function used in the example.
solver.Minimize(solver.Sum([y[j] for j in data['bins']]))

## With the addition of a variable cost for a bin, you may need the following.
solver.Minimize(solver.Sum([y[j] * data['bin_cost'] for j in data['bins']]))
```